# Socket.io + node : TypeError: Object #<Namespace> has no method

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, socket.io, typeerror

I have a simple JavaScript class like that :

> ```
> function MySIOClass(io)
> {
>     this.io = io
>     this.ns = this.io.of('/notif')
>     this.init()
> }
>
> MySIOClass.prototype.init = function (){
>   this.ns.on('connection', this.newClient)
> }
>
> MySIOClass.prototype.newClient = function (socket)
> {
>   socket.on('msg', function (data){ this.handle_msg(data)})
> ```
>
> }
>
> ```
> MySIOClass.prototype.handle_msg = function (data)
> {
>     // handle my message
> }
> ```

I get stuck on the function *newClient*, each time a *socket.io* client send an event 'msg', the console triggers

> **TypeError: Object #`<Socket>` has no method 'handle_msg'**

I tried to keep a reference of the operator *this* inside the function *newClient* like that :

> ```
> MySIOClass.prototype.newClient = function (socket)
> {
>   var c = this;
>   socket.on('msg', function (data){ c.handle_msg(data)})
> ```
>
> }

But no luck too, i got the following error about namespace :

> **TypeError: Object #`<Namespace>` has no method 'handle_msg'**

My class is exported via a module, everything works except when i try to add a listener  with the *on* method of *socket.io* inside a class. I have correctly used the "new" operator when i instantiated my class.

Could you help me figure out what's happening ? i tried several things, but none of them worked.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass `this.newClient` to `.on('connection', ...)`, you are passing just the function itself and losing the (`this`) context. You need to either create a wrapper function that can access the correct context to call `newClient()` properly or create a bound version of `newClient`.

First option:

```
MySIOClass.prototype.init = function (){
  var self = this;
  this.ns.on('connection', function(socket) {
    self.newClient(socket);
  });
}
```

Second option:

```
MySIOClass.prototype.init = function (){
  this.ns.on('connection', this.newClient.bind(this));
}
```

Regarding the error inside `newClient()` itself, you are correct in that you have to use a "self"/"that" variable that you can use to access the correct context to call `handle_msg()`.

Comment: Thanks !!! worked! I understand better now. The problem was not only on the callee, but also in the caller. Personally i prefer the second solution ;).